# STOP asterisk duplicate SIP INVITE

Tags: asterisk, sip, voip

Is there any way to stop duplicate INVITE in asterisk SIP message a?
We are using Asterisk 1.8.10
Inbound Call flow to VoIP/SIP is as follows:-
SIP trunk -> Asterisk 1.8 -> VOIP app
When we get call from SIP provide/trunk asterisk generate duplicate 2 SIP INVITE messages to VOIP app unable to handle it. Is there any way to stop it from asterisk side.
Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Asterisk send second invite only if

1) first invite was not confirmed. You app should answer OK(confirm).

2) reinvite requested.

You can try increase t1/t2 timer  to increase delay in 1). For disable reinvite, see directmedia option.